# cross domain iFrames communication problem

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

- I have a page A containing 2 children iFrames called B and C.
- A and B are on different domains.
- On pressing a button in B I would like to change C's URL.

Based on the [law III](http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes) of Michael Mahemoff it should work, but in fact it doesn't (js security error).

Here is the JS code in B:

```
window.parent.frames['C'].location.href = "http://random.url";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does not work because frame B cannot access the `frames` collection in page A.

I cannot think of any workaround (other than setting `document.domain`)

Comment: and you can only adjust `document.domain` within certain constraints.

Answer (score 0):

in case a page & frame are not on the same domain, you'll have to use [postmessage](http://ejohn.org/blog/postmessage-api-changes/), which is part of html5 and [works in all modern browsers (including IE8)](http://a.deveria.com/caniuse/#feat=x-doc-messaging).

if you need support for older browsers (specifally IE6/7), you could use the [jQuery postmessage plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/postmessage) (which transparently falls back to some nice hash-tag trickery for older browsers).